# Implementing push notifications if using Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-realtime-database

I am building a WhatsApp like chat app using Firebase.
I want the notification system to be exactly like WhatsApp.

According to the docs this means I need to implement upstream messenging using XMPP(which I have no clue what it is).

How should I go about it as I can't find any sample server side codes for this.

I am using Realtime Database to store the chat msgs, would I need to store msgs in my own server now.

Comment: I think you should try their codelabs like [Friendly Chat app](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/). This is a good way to learn how to use the Firebase platform to easily create Android applications. You will implement a chat client and be able to monitor its performance using Firebase (includes chat, Realtime Database, and notification). You don't need to own a server because in Firebase your Realtime Database is your server.

Comment: I have done that already. The only way to send notifications is through the console,there is no upstream messenging sample.